# How to loop over a field's value one after another and do aggregation operations on it?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I recently started working with MongoDB and its aggregation pipeline. I need some help with looping over the field called `Id` and doing aggregation operation on it one after another directly inside pipeline.

Currently I am doing something like this (in Node.js):

```
let patients = await client.db('MyDB').collection('Patients_MA').find().toArray();
let patientColl = client.db('MyDB').collection('Patients_MA');

for (int i=0; i<patients.length; i++)
{
    doc = patientColl.aggregate([
      {
        $match: {Id: patients[i].Id}
      }, 
      {
        $project: {
          _id: 0, 
          num: {
            $add: [
              {$multiply: [0.7, 2]},
              {$multiply: [0.2, 2]},
              {$multiply: [0.15, 0]}
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    ]);

    await patientColl.updateOne(
        { "Id": id },
        { "$set": {'heuristic': num} }
    );
}
```

For the sake of easy understanding I have condensed the pipeline to just the main thing I want it to do which is to update the `heuristic` value but in my original pipeline, each `Id` will have a different `heuristic` value. Also, I have approximately 8000 patients Ids and in my original pipeline, I am working with 3 different collection.

So my question is, is there a way to loop over each `Id`'s, run the the pipeline above, and update the `heuristic` value directly inside the aggregation pipeline? Or a way to do this more efficiently without having to make O(8000) calls?

Edit: Here's the [link](https://pastebin.com/jpbv7MY3) to the original pipeline.

Comment: Are there `Id` values in `patientColl` that don't exist in `Patients_MA`?

Comment: `patientColl` and `Patients_MA` are using the same collection so no. And there arent any null `Id` values either. I have edited the post accordingly. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Can `"heuristic"` be determined from other fields with each document?

Comment: Yeah. Thats how I am doing it in my original pipeline. I have added a pastebin link to it above. But yeah in my original pipeline, I am getting 4 values from 3 different collections (2 values from the same coll) to calculate the `heuristic` value. And thats the value I wanna calculate for each patient and set it for each of their `Id`.

Comment: There's a pastebin link?

Comment: Just added it..

Comment: Ignoring most of the logic from your pastebin, if you want the results for each patient, couldn't you just drop the initial `"$match"` and then include `"Id"` in each `"$match"` before `"$group"`, and also include `"Id"` in the `"$replaceRoot"` and final `"$project"`?

Comment: I dont think that'll be possible since my `encounters_MA` and `conditions_MA` collections have multiple occurrences of the same patient `Id`s. If it is still possible, could you give me an example of what you meant by your answer? I am still new to mongodb aggregation so idk how to implement it properly.